# How should an ask timeout be handled by the askee? Is it even possible?

Tags: scala, akka

Suppose I have some client code that uses akka's `ask` pattern on an actor:

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(1.minute)
val result: Future[Any] = actor ? Question
```

And the actor handles it like this:

```
def receive = {
  case Question =>
    // work work work
    // 3 minutes later...
    sender ! Answer
}
```

The `result` Future is expected to time out in this scenario, since the reply would be sent after three minutes but the given timeout was only one minute.

Does akka's ask pattern do anything to notify the "askee" that there was a timeout? Is there a way to handle this, e.g. to cancel any remaining work that the actor might have done if there was not a timeout?

Comment: Short answer is No.  An actor cannot be interrupted from processing the current message that it's handling.  Any communication with the actor takes place via messages (even things like stopping) and that new message won't be handled until the current one is finished.  Now, if your actor farmed out part of the work and then switched state to wait for a response then it could handle another message to tell it to stop and not finish any other work after that first response came back but you'd need to code that yourself.  Ask itself does not handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

So you need a mecanism to stop a long running computation taking place in the askee, whether or not the asker timed out.

### A solution

First of all, only the askee knows how to deal with its own computation. Therefore, it is the only one who can gracefully stop it.

A common way of dealing with this is to pass a `maximumTime` to the askee in the message indicating the maximum amount of time for it to send a completed answer.

Then, while computing its result, the askee can periodically check if the maximum time has been reached either throw a `TimeoutException` or send a `Failure` to the asker:

```
def receive = {
  case MessageWithTimeout(msg, maximumTime) => compute(msg, maximumTime)
}

def compute(msg: Message, maximumTime: Long): T {
  val startTime = System.nanoTime()
  // ...
  // somewhere during the computation:
  if(System.nanoTime() - startTime > maximumTime) {
      throw new TimeoutException(maximumTime + "exceeded")
  }
  // ...
}
```

Doing so, the askee will stop the computation after `maximumTime`.

If you send the same timeout as the one of the asker, then it is likely that the asker will timeout while waiting, and only then the askee will stop its computation and return.

It is to be noted that if you throw an Exception, then the behavior for the actors should be delegated to the supervisor.

Answer (score 2):

This is not built in, but you could accomplish something close to this if the actor is prepared for a cancellation.

In your sender, you could do something like:

```
...
val actorForClosure = actor
future onFailure { case _ : AskTimeoutException => actorForClosure ! Cancel }
```

However, the actor would have to be able to handle a cancellation. If it blocks for 3 minutes, then the cancel request would not get in until after the computation was completed and be pointless. But, if you can break your computation up into chunks that iterate back onto itself, then you could leave a gap for the Cancel to come in between computation. So, cancellation has to be baked in from the start.